# `objects()` in R vs. Splus

Tags: r, s-plus

I would like to write a script `main.r` that returns the workspace to the state it was in before being run (i.e., at the end of the script, remove all and only the objects that had been added to the workspace). Running the following:

```
#main.r
initial.objects <- objects()
tmp1 <- 1
remove(list = setdiff(objects(), initial.objects)
```

via `source('main.r')` from the R console works as desired. HOWEVER, this does NOT work in Splus with `tmp1` being left in the working directory (it does work when I run each line individually rather than sourcing the entire file). Investigating a little further, I found that in R `objects()` keeps track of the objects entering the workspace even in the MIDDLE of a call to `source()`. In Splus, `objects()` doesn't seem to "know" about the objects that have been added to the workspace until the END of a `source()` call.

Q: What's going on? What can I do to get something similar to `main.r` working in Splus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but the best way to reload an environment is to save it and reload it.

```
save("pre-environ.Rdata")
## Your script goes here
rm(list=ls()) ## clean the environment
## Reload the original environ at end of your script
load("pre-environ.Rdata")
```

Comment: that certainly seems easier. In Splus `save` and `load` are replaced by `data.dump` and `data.restore`

Comment: When removing, don't forget about variables starting in '.': rm(list=ls(all.names=TRUE))

Comment: Thanks for that addition Ian, although, I would say that using "." is poor style, especially when it creates extra considerations like this!